# How Swift code is excecuted in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I've got a Problem. I'm new to iOS programming, and i'm struggling to understand how Swift code is excecuted. For example, in the piece of code below, I would think that every line is executed right after the one above. But when it reaches the **passData()** function, it does not ejecute that fuction. it keeps going, and some time later (or erlier) it excecutes it (the passData function).

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    if numLaunches == 0{
        nombre = usuario()
        numLaunches += 1
    }
}
```

---

```
func usuario() -> String {
    var tField: UITextField!

    func configurationTextField(textField: UITextField!)
    {
        print("generating the TextField")
        textField.placeholder = "Enter an item"
        textField.textAlignment = .center
        tField = textField
    }

    func handleCancel(alertView: UIAlertAction!)
    {
        print("Cancelled !!")
    }

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Please Enter Your Name", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)

    alert.addTextField(configurationHandler: configurationTextField)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler:handleCancel))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: .default, handler:{ (UIAlertAction) in
        print("Done !!")

        print("Item : \(String(describing: tField.text))")
        self.nombre = tField.text!
    }))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: {
        print("completion block")
    })
    print(self.nombre)
    passData()
    if tField.text == nil {
        return "No value"
    }else{
        return (tField.text!)
    }
}

func passData() {
    let myVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondVC") as! AboutViewController
    if myVC.playerName != nil {
        myVC.playerName.text = nombre
    }else{

    }
    navigationController?.pushViewController(myVC, animated: true)
    print("pasa el dato")
}
```

So, the Problem is, that i need to pass the content of the variable "**nombre**" to another VC. But when the passData function is excecuted that variable is empty. I thought if i called that function after the variable was updated, it Will pass the right content. But im clearly mistaken.

I would appreciate the help!

Comment: @dfd That's a little harsh.  This is a totally valid question clearly regarding a misunderstanding about completion handlers with `UIAlertAction`.  It has nothing to do with threading, and a Google on OOP and MVC wouldn't help here either.

Comment: @dfd Whatever.  The dude's a student from a non-English speaking country.  I think it's ok to read the full question and be a bit forgiving of the way the question is written.

Comment: sorry @dfd . I've tried to ask it the best i could. i'm new to all this. im sure practice will help to understand this better.

Comment: @dfd There is an edit option beneath the question asked. Maybe you should suggest one. You understand that the user is new, so help him. Teach him how to word his question effectively and guide him to "How to ask a good question on stack overflow" page: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, unless your functions are asynchronous, you are correct in your understanding that code is executed from top down.  In this case I think you are just confused about your `UIAlertAction` code.  It appears you are popping an alert to the user, asking them to write their name, and when they hit "Done" you want to call your `passData()` function.  In that case, you should put that `passData()` call *inside* your `UIAlertAction`, like so:

```
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: .default, handler:{ (UIAlertAction) in
    print("Done !!")

    print("Item : \(String(describing: tField.text))")
    self.nombre = tField.text!
    self.passData()
}))
```

The code inside the handler for your `UIAlertAction`s will not be executed until the user presses that button, which is why you are finding that `passData` is getting called too early.

Comment: Thanks! This actually helped me!

Comment: Excellent answer! From the basic coding we learn, we are used to seeing code being compiled in a linear fashion, line by line. 
But, this is the beauty of multithreading. Concurrency is a way to perform multiple tasks at the same time.